# How to use tensorflow's FFT?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am having some trouble reconciling my FFT results from MATLAB and TF. The results are actually very different. Here is what I have done:

1). I would attach my data file here but didn't find a way to do so. Anyways, my data is stored in a .mat file, and the variable we will work with is called 'TD'. In MATLAB, I first subtract the mean of the data, and then perform fft:

```
f_hat = TD-mean(TD);
x = fft(f_hat);
```

2). In TF, I use

```
tf.math.reduce_mean
```

to calculate the mean, and it only differs from MATLAB's mean on the order of 10^-8. So in TF I have:

```
mean_TD = tf.reduce_mean(TD)
f_hat_int = TD - mean_TD
f_hat_tf = tf.dtypes.cast(f_hat_int,tf.complex64)
x_tf = tf.signal.fft(f_hat_tf)
```

So up until 'f_hat' and 'f_hat_tf', the difference is very slight and is caused only by the difference in the mean. However, x and x_tf are very different. I am wondering did I not use TF's FFT correctly?

Thanks!

[Picture showing the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclCW.png)

Comment: I have also tried to use all tensors as complex128. I got about the same discrepancy.

Comment: What kind of differences do you see? Is the spectrum completly different? Or just scaled in any way (amplitude/frequencies)?

Comment: Hey Arno. Thank you for helping. I added a link for a figure in my original post that shows the differences I am getting. In short, it is completely different, nothing like a scale or shifting issue.

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out if you want to pass in an array to tf.fft(), then this array has to be a 1D NumPy array but not a 2D NumPy array with one of the dimensions = 1.